# Pairing Watson Assistant and Watson Language Translator

Tags: pairing

I want know about how to run multilingual in Watson Chatbot. How to pair watson assistant chatbot and watson language translator?? Im trying Webhooks to translate language to another language but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

the best way for this is to use Watson Language Translator (WLT) before sending the sentence to Watson Assistant (WA) and then again after getting the answer.
Do this programmatically using the language of your choice.

For instance, if you have a skill in English and I am using French.

- Sentence in french
- translation french to english with WLT API call
- send to WA in english
- get answer in english
- tranalisation english to french with WLT
- answer in french

Of course the best is still to have a skill in your language but this is a way to have quickly a version in another language.

Webhooks cannot be used for this as it is done to get or send data from WA.

I had an example of this using node-red in a lab I did a while ago. Let me know if it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks will not work since the intent and entity detection happens before the webhook is hit.

So in order to make this work, we will have to

1. First call the preHandler which could detect the input language of the user(say french) and then convert it to the language in which the bot is built in(lets say English).
2. Set the context variable of input language to the language of the user interacting in(french)
3. Once you receive the response back from WA, have a postHandler which can convert the same response back to the language of the user(french) getting that information from the context variable of language.